# How can I fill in a CharSequence array from the property of a object List in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I hope to get both *name* and *_id* of *MSetting* of *myList*, and fill in both *entries* and *entryValues* with them, how can I do in Kotlin ?

At present , I have to use Code A to do it, but it's too complex!

**Code A**

```
for(aMetting in myList){
   entries.add(aMetting.name)
   entriesValue.add(aMetting._id)
}
```

**Source**

```
var entries = arrayOf<CharSequence>()
var entryValues = arrayOf<CharSequence>()


var myList: List<MSetting>

data class MSetting (
        var _id: Long,  
        var name: String,
        var createdDate: Long,
        var description: String
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you really need to put `_id` and `name` in two different arrays. however, to do so you can use `forEach` statement:

```
myList.forEach { it -> entries.add(it.name); entriesValue.add(it._id) }
```

but if you want to don't loose `_id` and `name` relations. you can use `Pair` structure.

```
val entries = mutableListOf<Pair<CharSequence, CharSequence>>()
myList.forEach { it -> entries.add(Pair(it._id, it.name)) }
```

using `Map` is another option, but it's recommended if you have the keys and want to find values. to iterate over all entries, there is no meaningful differences.

Answer (score 0):

I think that rather than using  separate arrays, you can put it in a Map

`val settingMap = hashMapOf ( name to id )` or
`val map = mutableMapOf<Integer, String>()`

```
for((key, value) in settingMap){
    println(value)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*

var myList = ArrayList<MSetting>()

var entryMap = HashMap<Long, String>()

data class MSetting (
        var _id: Long,
        var name: String,
        var createdDate: Long,
        var description: String
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    myList.forEach { entryMap.put(it._id, it.name) }
}
```